# How do I include JS files in a Swig template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swig-template

I am creating a web application in Node.js, Express 3.0, and Swig (among other things). On one of my templates I want to "include" a JavaScript file. I noticed the feature exists in Jade but could not figure out how to do it in Swig. If this feature does exist, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: You mean [this](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/tags/#include)?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. Are you asking to include with `<script src="myfile.js></script>`, or are you asking to include another template into your current one, which may or may not be a JavaScript file?

Comment: I would like to know how I can include a JS file, like '<script src="myfile.js></script>'. I can't actually remember why I wanted to do this, as it seems simply including a file that contains would get the job done. I believe my motivation was cleaner code, but I'm not sure. Thanks for you help anyway, that include tag should do the trick!